# Tag wiki color bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The editing pages for tag wikis are not very legible, see screenshot below:
[image: Tag wiki editing page screenshot]

Comment: I'm fixing this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.